# How to get list of all my facebook friends using facebook api?

Tags: facebook

How to get list of all my facebook friends. I am using the api https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends using the access token. It is only giving me friends list who are already using the app. I want all my friend.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name,picture&access_token='.$fbtoken; I am collecting accesstoken when user is loggedin with facebook. It is always getting freshaccess token. api is giving me list of two friends who are already using the app and a summary of total friends 391 but not their details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intentional, since v2.0 you can only get the friends who authorized your App too, for privacy reasons. An App should not be able to get data of friends who don´t use the App. See the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Also, see this thread (and countless others) about the same topic: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: Thanks. I have seen the changelog. Is there any alternative to get my friendlist.